# Updating Jtable after deleting from DB

Tags: java, swing, derby

i'm trying to remove the deleted row from the jtable but since it's a primary key (client id ) i can't just update its table only i have to update the tables where it's a foreign key in ( animal and appointment(rv)) but how i can make it happen i tried to refill the tables from the DB after deleting but didn't work

```
int f = table.getSelectedRow();
if(f != -1) { 
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Confirm the Delete", "Warning!!!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) ) 
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        String l = table.getModel().getValueAt(f,0).toString();
        int l1 = Integer.parseInt(l);

        try { 
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\user pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\project\\projet","root","root");
            Statement stm= cnx.createStatement(); 
            stm.executeUpdate("delete from rv where cid="+l1+"");
            stm.executeUpdate("delete from animal where cid="+l1+" ");
            stm.executeUpdate("delete from client where id="+l1+"");  
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(all.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(all.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(all.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }             
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select the row you want to delete");
    }
}
```

Comment: "i tried to refill the tables from the DB after deleting but didn't work". Why it did not work? After the update you just reload data from DB and populate your table models.

Comment: exactly that's exactly what i tried to do but it doesn't work it just stays there until i relaunch the app

Comment: Did you fire change events from your model after the reloading the data?

Comment: well no i don't think soo what is that ??

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html. You can start with `fireTableStructureChanged` and see if it helps. If it does you can try to play with other `fire` methods to fine tune table updates since `fireTableStructureChanged` is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove the selected row:

```
[...]
try { 
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\user pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\project\\projet","root","root");
    Statement stm= cnx.createStatement(); 
    stm.executeUpdate("delete from rv where cid="+l1+"");
    stm.executeUpdate("delete from animal where cid="+l1+" ");
    stm.executeUpdate("delete from client where id="+l1+"");  

    ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(f);
} [...]
```

Comment: but the animal and appointment jtables won't be updated in this case only client jtable will be updated